# Macro String with variable

Tags: c++, c

I don't know how to define a macro string with variable, like this:
`#define str(x) "file x.txt"`, that mean I desire that str(1) refers to "file 1.txt".
However, in the case, str(1) or any number refers to "file x.txt", because x is an character.
Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: The "with variable" might be tricky. If you have `int foo=5; STR(foo)` you're still talking about `file foo.txt`, not `file 5.txt`. Macro's work at compile time, before variables have values assigned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concatenate the strings:

```
#define STR(x) "file " #x ".txt"
```

This makes use of a lexical feature of the two languages: adjacent string literals are concatenated; see both C++11 2.2/6 and C11 5.1.1.2/6:

> Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define str(x) ("file " #x ".txt")
```

using the stringification operator `#`